# Word macro to retrieve a style's formatting and select all texts with the same formatting

Tags: microsoft-word, macros, microsoft-word-2013

I know it’s possible to select text based on their formatting (with the find/replace feature) but I would like to do that automatically, without having to manually enter the font, font color, italic etc.

So I am looking for a macro that would retrieve the formatting of `Heading 1` (its font, the font color, the size, if it's bold/italic/underline). Then the macro would search my document for any text that matches this formatting.

The macro should select all paragraphs with the `Heading 1` style but also all other paragraphs with other styles but with the same font, font color, size and bold/italic/underline like `Heading 1`.

Comment: SuperUser is not a free script writing service. If you try writing the macro yourself and get stuck, you can ask this community for advice on how to fix your problem.

Comment: I could write the macro if I had this function: "retrieve formatting of a specific heading" and if I knew how to use it. The rest should look like that: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_mac/word-macro-for-applying-format-styles-not-working/59155ecf-7fe4-4757-8c5d-ca5b2bced63d

Comment: You can retrieve a `Style` object for Heading 1 using `ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleHeading1)`. Then you can query its properties. For example `ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleHeading1).Font.Bold` will return True, False, or wdUndefined.

Comment: @Atzmon thanks a lot! I will try it, I'll publish the code when it'll work